# Android install package if intent fails

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an application that uses Navigation. The problem is that if the device doesn't have the Navigation app, the application crash with an exception. Time before I did another application that checks if the package exists and if not, the application redirects to you to the market.

How can I do that? Is that a generic check? Or was it only for the package that I used?

Also... if I can check it, I could try to do the intent and if I catch the exception, then redirect to market... the question is, how can I redirect to the market?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Intent with `market://details?id=<package_name>` URL to invoke apps page on market.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html), it explains how to check if an `Intent` can be resolved, or if it will throw an `ActivityNotFoundException`. This way, if the `Intent` can't be resolved you can instead launch the Market (check out **Peter**'s link) and point the user to the application.